# TStringList CustomSort method on Name/Value pairs

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is is posssible to use customSort on a TStringList using the Name from the Name/Value pairs

I was currently using a TStringList to sort one value in each pos. I now need to add additional data with this value and therefor I am now using the TStringList as Name/Values

My current CompareSort is:

```
function StrCmpLogicalW(sz1, sz2: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall;
  external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'StrCmpLogicalW';


function MyCompare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrCmpLogicalW(PWideChar(List[Index1]), PWideChar(List[Index2]));
end;
Usage:
  StringList.CustomSort(MyCompare);
```

is there a way to modify this so that it sorts based on the Name of the name value pairs?

Or, is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function MyCompare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrCmpLogicalW(PWideChar(List.Names[Index1]), PWideChar(List.Names[Index2]));
end;
```

But actually, I think yours should work as well, since the string itself starts with the name anyway, so sorting by the entire string implicitly sort it by name.

Comment: Where is this function?

Comment: @AdrianMaire What function? MyCompare is mine StrCmpLogicalW is an Windows API function declared in the question.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this you use the [`Names`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Names) indexed property which is described in the documentation like this:

> Indicates the name part of strings that are name-value pairs.
>
> When the list of strings for the TStrings object includes strings that
>   are name-value pairs, read Names to access the name part of a string.
>   Names is the name part of the string at Index, where 0 is the first
>   string, 1 is the second string, and so on. If the string is not a
>   name-value pair, Names contains an empty string.

So, instead of `List[Index1]` you simply need to use `List.Names[Index1]`. Your compare function thus becomes:

```
function MyCompare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrCmpLogicalW(
    PChar(List.Names[Index1]), 
    PChar(List.Names[Index2])
  );
end;
```